# Making the player lose lives

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am doing a health counter with sprite images for a block breaker game. The problem is that when the ball hits the collider he automatically goes to the Lose scene without losing any lives. The user is supposed to lose a life each time the ball touches the collider and when he runs out of lives, the user goes to the lose scene but none of these are working.

I do not know if I am meant to change something or add something to one of my scripts. Can someone help me, please? Thank you.

The below image is for you to see the Ball inspector
[image: Ball ins[pector]

The below image is for you to see the Heart 1,2,3 and 4 inspector
[image]

Lives script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Lives : MonoBehaviour
{
public int health;
public int NumberOfHearts;
public LoadScenes LoadLevel;
public LevelManager lvlManager;
public Image[] hearts; //Creating an arry.
public Sprite FullHeart;
public Sprite EmptyHeart;


void Update()
{
    if(health > NumberOfHearts) //This is to make sure that the ball doesn't go over 4 lives
    {
        health = NumberOfHearts;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++) //Variable i is less than the length of hearts 
    {
        if (i < health) //If i is smaller than the health
        {
            hearts[i].sprite = FullHeart; //The sprite of FullHeart is displayed
        }
        else
        {
            hearts[i].sprite = EmptyHeart; //The sprite of EmptyHeart is displayed
        }

        if (i < NumberOfHearts)//For loop to check if i is smaller than the NumberOfHearts
        {
            hearts[i].enabled = true; //If i IS smaller than the NumberOfHearts than hearts of the index i is visiable
        }
        else
        {
            hearts[i].enabled = false; //If it ISN'T smaller than the NumberOfHearts than hearts of the index i is invisiable
        }

        if (NumberOfHearts < 0)
        {
            lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
        }

     }

  }

}
```

LoadScene script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour {

public LevelManager lvlManager;

//If the ball hits one of the walls the colliders will be triggered
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    print("The wall is triggered by the ball");
    lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    Bricks.brickCount = 0;


}



  void OnCollisionEnter2D()
   {
      Debug.Log("The ball has collided with the wall");
   }

}
```

LevelManager script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
  public void LoadLevel(string name)
  {
    print("Level loading requested for" + name);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I noticed in your LoadScene script:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    print("The wall is triggered by the ball");
    lvlManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    Bricks.brickCount = 0;
}
```

You basically told it to trigger the Lose game scene immediately whereas you should have called a function to reduce a heart and then update the health in which it will check the updated number of hearts and then let it decide if the game is lost or not

Comment: Should i call the void Update() from the Lives script onto the LoadScene ?

Comment: Try to read this guide on Lives script ("https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-health") by Unity if you haven't already.. It is quite different but what you are doing right now but after understanding that you would be able clear you current and future doubts yourself